# Could someone explain the use of: *, *::before, *::after in CSS

Tags: css

I'm currently taking the freeCodeCamp Responsive Web Design Certification course and I really wish someone could explain to me a bit more of the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements..

While I can use:

```
 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

What's the reason of using:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I'm not fully understanding the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements.. Feel free to recommend videos, or articles.. I'm just really not getting the reason. (new to all of this, sorry for being a newbie)

Comment: pseudo-elements are not selected by default with the wildcard selector. Therefore it makes sense to reset the box model for pseudo-elements that way too. However, this expects that pseudo-elements are set as block-level elements. Pseudo-elements are not elements that actually exist within the DOM but will be added through CSS. This gives the ability to add elements for styling purposes. In some cases, they are misused as a hack to add more information such as a currency to a money input. This however works against accessibility rules.

Comment: [Here](https://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/) you can read why the before/after, and not just `*`